# Format text of mark_text in Altair

Tags: altair

I'm trying to create a chart somewhat along the lines of the [Multi-Line Tooltip example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_tooltip.html), but I'd like to format the string that is being printed to have some text added at the end. I'm trying to modify this part:

```
# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'y:Q', alt.value(' '))
)
```

Specifically, rather than 'y:Q' I want something along the lines of 'y:Q' + " suffix". I've tried doing something like this:

```
# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'y:Q', alt.value(' '), format=".2f inches")
)
```

Alternatively, I've tried:

```
# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
y_fld = 'y'
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, f"{y_fld:.2f} inches", alt.value(' '))
)
```

I think I see why those don't work, but I can't figure out how to intercept the value of y and pass it through a format string. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to calculate a new field using `transform_calculate` to compute the label that you want.

Using the example from the documentation, I would change the text chart like this:

```py
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'label:N', alt.value(' '))
).transform_calculate(label='datum.y + " inches"')
```

That leads to this chart:
[image]

If you want more control, you could change the dataset with pandas beforhand. Be sure to set the type to Nominal (and not Quantitative) otherwise you would get `NaN`s in the tooltips.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't quite sure what datum was but it seems to be an altair convention. I also wanted to round the values which I was able to do as follows, for anyone else slightly confused:

`.transform_calculate(label=f'format(datum.{fld},".1f") + " inches"')`

Comment: datum is vega&#39;s way to access data. There is more information in the documentation https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform.html
Good job on formatting your data!